# Guarantee disk cache was flushed with fsync

Tags: buffer, flush, hard-drive

I understand that `fsync` [system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) moves dirty data from kernel buffer cache (page cache) to HDD. Does it guarantee that hard disk moved said data from its internal cache to platter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I read the documentation once again and it clearly states (redacted):

> fsync() transfers ... all modified in-core data of ... the file
>   referred to by the file descriptor fd to the disk device ...   so that
>   all changed information can be retrieved even after system
>   crashed ...  **This includes writing through or 
>   flushing a disk cache if present.**